# Without sorting finding minimum 10 element in array

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, select, minimum

ı need to find minimum ten element in array which has 1000 inordered numbers.
I firstly think like: sort it and select first ten element but my duty is doing same thing without sorting. By the way ı am using C programming. Can you help me ?

Comment: I can help! Write int minimums[10];

Comment: A further hint: you only need to consider the "greatest minimum" you have thus far when iterating the numbers. If it's less than your greatest minimum, then you simply remove the greatest minimum (and keep that `minimums` array sorted)

Comment: Hint: this is like the C++ standard algorithm nth_element. Find out how that’s implemented, then get the 10th element.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using a max heap of maximum size 10 you can achieve this in `O(n * log(10) = O(n)` time complexity as follows:

1. Initialize a max heap, `hp`.
2. Add the first 10 elements of the input array to the heap.
3. Iterate over the remaining elements of the heap and do the following for each one of them:

- Compare the element with the element at the tip of the heap.
- If it's smaller, pop one from the heap and push the element onto the heap.

4. At the end of the loop, you have a heap that holds the 10 smallest elements of the input array. The element at the tip of the heap, is the 10th smallest. Return it.